# Errors while trying to compile OpenCV project on Dev C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, dev-c++

Im getting this error:

```
D:\Users\JF150696\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrDYwyp.o Source2.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
D:\Users\JF150696\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrDYwyp.o Source2.cpp:(.text+0xdec): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
D:\Users\JF150696\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrDYwyp.o Source2.cpp:(.text+0xe41): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
d:\devc\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe  D:\Users\JF150696\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrDYwyp.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.text$_ZSt4sqrtf[__ZSt4sqrtf]'
D:\devc\opencv\projekty\test 3 opencv\test 3 opencv\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

What i did in Dev Options:

1. I have added this command line to compiler:

   -L"C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib" -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_core248 -lopencv_imgproc248 -lopencv_calib3d248 -lopencv_video248 -lopencv_features2d248 -lopencv_ml248 -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_objdetect248 -lopencv_contrib248 -lopencv_legacy248 -lopencv_flann248
2. This lane to linker options:

   -static-libgcc -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_core248 -lopencv_imgproc248 -lopencv_calib3d248 -lopencv_video248 -lopencv_features2d248 -lopencv_ml248 -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_objdetect248 -lopencv_contrib248 -lopencv_legacy248 -lopencv_flann248
3. In directiories i have added:

   binaries: `D:\devc\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin`

   libs: `D:\devc\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib`

   headers C: `D:\devc\opencv\build\include\opencv2` `D:\devc\opencv\build\include\opencv` `D:\devc\opencv\build\include`

   headers C++: same as above
4. I have added opencv path `D:\devc\opencv` to PATH variable
5. My dev C++ version is: 5.7.0, OpenCV: 2.4.8

Anyone know how to fix that?

**EDIT**

Same problem using CodeBlock

Comment: I have simular problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867017/setting-opencv-2-4-9-on-orwell-devc-5-7-1

Comment: Hey, have you find any solution, I know is too late but I have the same problem, if you remember the solution can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Did you link Source2 to collect2 properly?  Source2.cpp should be compiled into an object file before linking with your main program.

Comment: Source2.cpp is a main program - it is kind of strange name indeed :D there is no other c or cpp file

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the problems are not related to **linking libraries** it is because **imread and imwrite shouldnt be like you called**

> imread(string, mat)

But you called

> imread(string, int)

So it gives error. Same with other lines.

Comment: u are wrong, but ty for trying to help. according to opencv docs: [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread). It is linking error becouse it checks error (e.g i will change 2nd argument to Mat). What is more i can run that code on VS12, but i need to be able to run it on dev aswell

Comment: then, what is `undefined reference to cv::imread(std::string const&, int)`? Could you send the line where it gives this error?

Comment: i pasted all log. there is no line pointed becouse it is linking error. but here u go, this is probably that line:
`Mat img = imread("Manulane2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

Answer (score 0):

Build the libraries using CMake and CodeBlocks as given in [here](http://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/how-to-install-opencv-on-windows-7-64bit-using-mingw-64-and-codeblocks/) till step 3 of codeblock settings.

Then include the following as given in the blog to Devc++ C and C++ Includes tab

```
C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\include
C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\include\opencv
C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\include\opencv2
```

since you have included opencv and opencv2, remove /opencv2/..and /opencv ..in the header files.

and add the below line to libraries in Devc++
    C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\x64\mingw\lib

also add all the .dll.a files in C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\x64\mingw\lib  to Project Options.
 Copy all the dll files from opencv\my_build\install\x64\mingw\bin and paste to folder where EXE of your program would be built.